# Is it possible to read property from portal-ext.properties using JavaScript or api/jsonws in Liferay 7.1?

Tags: liferay-7.1

I am defining the AMD module under OSGi module. I have to read **host** property in AMD loader definition. how can I read the property from portal-ext.properties file?

below is sample code how I am defining the AMD module and property in portal-ext.properties file.

### portal-ext.properties

```
# host detail
host={{host_url}}
```

### define AMD module

```
Liferay.Loader.define('genelec-shopping-cart', [], function(){
    const host = ""; //here i have to read the property
    return{
        getHost:function(){
            return host;
        },
    };
});
```

Comment: Show us the code, please.

Comment: What's the underlying root problem that you're trying to solve with this?

Comment: please help me @GiovanniDiToro, I put the sample code as you told. Do you need more detailed info?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with ftl or jsp, building your JS with the value embedded.
Instead of creating the whole code from a JSP you can also just build a small portion of it, adding the value to a JS variable, making it available for scripts that will load later.

Let's say you have an OSGi module which JS code, you can create a .js.jsp that will build the JS before sending it.

Using JSP to create a small portion of JS:

```
<%@ page contentType='application/javascript' %>

//here i have to read the property -> do it in java

Liferay.Loader.define('genelec-shopping-cart', [], function(){
    const host = "${read_in_java}"; 
    return{
        getHost:function(){
            return host;
        },
    };
});
```

You can include it from other JSP files as:

```
<c:url var='url' value='/variables.js.jsp'>
    <c:param name='namespace' value='${namespace}'/>
</c:url>

<script src='${url}'></script>
```

But as you mentioned the host, you are probably looking for something much simpler than that (especially because this is kind of a hack), using Liferay's  JS api:

Liferay.ThemeDisplay.getPortalURL() and friends, docs here: 
https://dev.liferay.com/de/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-1/liferay-javascript-apis